# windows key, in logon screen

Tags: greeter, keyboard-shortcuts

experimenting with this distro, i stumbled across something odd. If you press the windows key on the logon screen, the screen rotate clockwise.
I can t find a key setting in the os that make this happen. When logged on it just show the key combinations.
Is the behavior that is "normal" to switch to tablet mode or something?.

Kind regards from the Dutch ;-)

Comment: just to add, the version is:

Comment: NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="5.1.7 Hera"
ID=elementary
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera"
LOGO=distributor-logo
VERSION_ID="5.1.7"
HOME_URL="https://elementary.io/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://elementary.io/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/new"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://elementary.io/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hera
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic